# Datebox date i18n in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

is it possible to display a GAS UI datebox's date in a different format than english?

For example I want to display the date in the german format dd.mm.yyyy.

Regards

Juri Wiens

Comment: Are you trying to just display the date or also enable inputting/editing of date in that format?

Answer (score 0):

There is an [open feature request](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1671) on the Issue Tracker to add this feature to GAS. Please star and follow it there!